# Turn off Clutter summary message in Office 365

Tags: office365

I have Clutter enabled in Outlook for Office 365 and periodically it sends me a message with the subject "Clutter moved new and different messages." Is there any way to disable this notification?

The message says "This system notification isn't an email message and you can't reply to it" at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [FAQ: Answers to common Office 365 Clutter questions](http://windowsitpro.com/blog/faq-answers-common-office-365-clutter-questions) this message cannot be disabled:

> ***What about those Clutter summary messages?*** Clutter creates summary messages to inform users about the processing that it does on
>   their behalf. You'll get one of these notifications on days that
>   Clutter finds a new or different sort of message to deal with. The
>   idea is that you can use these messages to double-check that nothing
>   important is being intercepted by Clutter. You can't turn these
>   notifications off.

Answer (score 2):

While you can't disable the message - you can create a rule in Outlook or OWA to move it or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

**2020 UPDATE (5 YEARS LATER)**

At the bottom of the clutter notification summary there are links to turn off notifications. **Dont bother clicking any of them, they dont actually work!** Pretty shocking, but seems the be the norm these days

[image]

Best bet is to use @JesusShelby answer above (good idea!)